# In backpropagation, why is weights_delta calculated as matrix multiplication of the outputs and delta? (and not of inputs and delta)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, backpropagation

I am going through [15 Steps to Implement a Neural Net](http://www.code-spot.co.za/2009/10/08/15-steps-to-implemented-a-neural-net/) and I'm stuck on Step 12 where I should implement my own backpropagation function. The neural network in question has only the input and the output layer and the weight matrix between them.

I was able to get this to work, but I had to modify one equation (line of code). I will go equation by equation and tell you where I had to modify things:

> First, select a random sample.
>
> Now, calculate the net matrix and output matrix using the feed-forward
> function.
>
> `[output, net] = feedforward(random_sample, weights, bias)`
>
> Calculate the error vector
>
> `error_vector = target_outputs - outputs`

This I understand. We are calculating the output from our current neural network with the current weights and then we are looking at how much error we have per each of the outputs.

Then the guide goes on:

> Calculate the sensitivity.
>
> `delta = hammard(error_vector, activation_diff(net))`
>
> The corresponding mathematical expression in the textbook might look
> like this:
>
> $δ_k=(t_k−z_k)f′(y_k)$

I addressed this in a [separate question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590342/can-someone-explain-the-use-of-delta-in-backpropagation), as things were a bit unclear to me here as well.

Finally, the guide says the following:

> Calculate the weights delta:
>
> `weights_delta = scalar_mul(eta, kronecker(transpose(outputs), delta))`
>
> The corresponding mathematical expression in the textbook might look
> like this: $w_kj=η(t_k−z_k)f′(y_k)y_j$
>
> Update the weights:
>
> `weights = add(weights, weights_delta)`
>
> and return the matrix.

I found the formula:

`weights_delta = scalar_mul(eta, kronecker(transpose(outputs), delta))`

to be incorrect. What I implemented (and what seems to work) is:

```
weights_delta = learning_rate * np.matmul(np.concatenate([random_sample, biases], axis=1).T, delta)
```

So I'm matrix multiplying the transposed inputs with delta, not Kronecker multiplying the transposed outputs and delta.

My question is: **Have I changed the `weights_delta = scalar_mul(eta, kronecker(transpose(outputs), delta))` line correctly? Does it make sense? If yes, someone explain the reasoning behind it, i.e., why is the first line faulty and the second one makes sense?** When I did it I was pretty much just looking at matrix dimensions and playing with them so they would match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the weight gradients are computed by multiplying gradients with inputs.

To see why this is, you can simply compute the gradient of the pre-activations (i.e. right before applying the activation function) w.r.t. weights:

$$\frac{\partial s_i}{\partial w_{jk}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial w_{jk}}\bigg(\sum_l w_{il} x_l\bigg) = [i = j]\,x_k,$$

where $[i=j]$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).
After all, this is what you will find in the chain rule that is used to compute the gradients:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{ij}} = \sum_a \underbrace{\frac{\partial L}{\partial s_a}}_{\delta_a} \underbrace{\frac{\partial s_a}{\partial w_{ij}}}_{[i=a]\,x_j} = \delta_i x_j.$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. I do have some additional questions for you though: 1) The formulas you provided are for every single matrix element, correct? 2) What does $x_k$ mean below the first equation? 3) How did you arrive at the Iverson bracket? 4) What is the a in the second equation?

Comment: 1) Yes, formulas are for single elements. 2) $x_k$ would be the $k$-th entry of the input vector (to the layer). 3) The derivative of $w_1$ w.r.t. $w_2$ is zero, whereas the derivative of $w_1$ w.r.t. $w_1$ is one. 4) The $a$ in the second equation arises from the fact that we have to consider "the route" through every (output) neuron when computing the gradients of the loss.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. Just to expand on your answer to question #4: the sum is there because when I compute the gradients of the loss, I have to consider all the neurons that enter a neuron for which I'm computing the derivative of the loss w.r.t. weights. Correct?

Comment: Not really. It would be the output neurons (not the input neurons) of the layer with the weights you are considering. Since discussions should be avoided, I would suggest you to look into the topics of multivariate and/or vector calculus if things are still unclear. Unfortunately, I do not really have any recommendations at hand.